# How to turn randomized color ramp node into a UV texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, node-editor

[image]

Hello, I have made this ice cream and I want to upload it to the game engine that I am using. However, I am facing one problem and it is the sprinkles. When I convert particle system, it will randomly pick one color from the color ramp and use that color for the rest.

Is there a way that I could quickly turn that color ramp node into uv texture? Or do I really have to convert, add a lot of materials and use the deselect random feature and assign it until I will achieve this? Because if that is what I would do then I would do it to all other 10+ ice creams and it takes so much time.

Thank you, I hope someone finds a quicker solution.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood correctly - to bake the RAMP into a texture, the most simple way is:

*(baked texture on the last image)*

1. **Scale the UV Map** of the **"Sprinkle"** super small
2. to **connect your RAMP to Emission** *(to retain colors vivid)*
3. **Create a New texture** called Colors
4. **Add the Image** texture to Shader Editor and select the Colors texture
5. In Render Options *(Cycles Render Engine)* BAKE, select **Emit** from dropdown
6. Hit **BAKE**

Then you can save *your texture as an Image*.

To use the texture, do not forget to plug in the **Math** node **"Add"** with **Random Object Info** node to the **Mapping**.

For the node setup in the first image, after Applying the Particle system, the sprinkles retained their various colors even without the Texture assigned.

Hope it helps!

[image: Node 1]
[image: Bake]

[image: Ramp]

Answer (score 1):

I believe in new versions of Blender the option is *Make Instances Real* instead of *Convert to Mesh*.

*Object Info* -> *Random* generates a value between 0-1 that is unique for each different object.  *Make Instances Real* will make a unique object for each particle, so the material should work as is.  However, when you *Convert to Mesh* all of the particles get joined under one object.

You can instead use *Geometry* -> *Random Per Island* to generate a unique value for **each mesh island that is a part of the object** and that should make your material work again with your current setup.

[image]

That is if I've got all the details right. :)